# Es posible agregar un archivo a un paquete .tar ya comprimido con bzip2 sin descomprimirlo

Tags: linux, bash, tar

¿Es posible agregar un archivo a un paquete de archivos .tar ya comprimidos?. Me explico mejor: tengo una archivo `mi_home.tar.bz2`, después que lo comprimí me di cuenta que me falto agregar un directorio al paquete .tar, pero ya lo comprimí con bzip2 a la máxima compresión `-9` o que es lo mismo `--best`, y de hecho es bastante pesada, pesa al menos 8Gb. El proceso de compresión tardó al menos 2 horas y media; si hago el proceso de nuevo tardaré no menos de 3 horas para descomprimir, agregar el directorio que me faltó al paquete tar y volver a comprimir nuevamente todo junto.

¿habrá un método mas eficiente de resolver esto, que no sea realizar el proceso de compresión de nuevo?

Comment: Lamentablemente no, el parámetro `-u` no funciona con archivos comprimidos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad si puedes realizar copias incrementales comprimidas de la siguiente manera:

```
tar --listed-incremental=snapshot.file --level=0 -cvzf backup.2.tar.gz /path/to/dir
```

Con --listed-incremental, tar crea un snapshot donde registra los cambios entre una copia y la siguiente, si no pusieras la opcion --level=0 tendrias que cambiar el destino de la copia cada vez que lo invocases y esto lo que crearia son copias sucesivas con solo los cambios entre el estado del backup anterior y el momento de la siguiente ejecucion.

Realizar esta operacion en modo incremental evitando el uso de --level=0 me parece una opcion mas adecuada dado que indicas que el tamaño de la copia esta empezando a ser un problema, es cierto que de esta manera tienes que preocuparte de lanzar el comando cambiando el tar.gz de destino dado que sino sobrescribirias lo comprimido "solo con las diferencias" pero eso lo podrias escriptar facilmente, asi mismo tendrias que procurar crear un directorio de destino donde ir acumulando las copias incrementales.